# Nested Code with Razor Syntax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that uses RAZOR. The app is basically a list of records with groups. In an attempt to generate a group heading and the records with each group, I'm using the following:

```
@{ string currentGroupName = string.Empty; }
@foreach (DataRow row in ViewBag.TableRows) {
  string groupName = Convert.ToString(row["Group"]); 
  if (groupName != currentGroupName) {
    <div style="width:98%;" class="nfo">@groupName</div>
    <table id="groupTable" border="0" class="t" style="margin-left:6px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    }
                  ...
  @if (groupName != currentGroupName) {
      </tbody>
    </table>
    currentGroupName = groupName;
  }
}
```

When I execute this code, I get an error that says:

```
Parser Error
The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take the @ off the if statement.  Unless you have other markup in between, you are still in code mode at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `@:` operator:

```
@{ string currentGroupName = string.Empty; }
@foreach (DataRow row in ViewBag.TableRows) 
{
    string groupName = Convert.ToString(row["Group"]); 
    if (groupName != currentGroupName) 
    {
        <div style="width:98%;" class="nfo">@groupName</div>
        @:<table id="groupTable" border="0" class="t" style="margin-left:6px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @:<tbody>
    }

    ...

    @if (groupName != currentGroupName) 
    {
            @:</tbody>
        @:</table>
        @{currentGroupName = groupName;}
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move `currentGroupName = groupName;` to the line right after the open bracket, you don't need the `@{...}` around it.